# In Bagging, how does one train the base learner?

Tags: ensemble-learning, bagging

In [Bagging](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-30/issue-4/Analyzing-bagging/10.1214/aos/1031689014.full) (the grouping of predictive variables), I can set a decision tree, a neural network, and so forth as the base learner, since I can get m datasets randomly, and in each dataset, I can train a base learner, and in the end, I have m base learners.

questions

1. Given m base learners, say $h_t(x),t=1,2,...,m$, to ensemble (*sic*, group) these learners, should I use some sort of weighting or set constraints to these learners? Or, is it all that can be done to average all the base learners as in $H(X)=\sum_{t=1}^{m}h_t(x)$? Is all the base learners should make

$H(x)=argmax_{y\epsilon{Y}}^{}\sum_{t=1}^{m}1(h_t(x)=y)$

2. Given m base learners, can a prediction or classification be performed for
   a new data?

Comment: I don't understand your question 1. setting weights of what?

Comment: @rep_ho, I added details of question 1.